# Как перевернуть текст с начала строки до указанного символа?

Tags: delphi

Как исправить код, чтобы текст переворачивался **с начала строки** и до указанного символа. То есть что бы **на выходе** получилось:

```
for i:=1 to n div 2 do    
begin
  c:=s[i];
  s[i]:=s[n-i+1];
  s[n-i+1]:=c;   
end;
```

Comment: Можете привести пример того, как ваш код неправильно работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, вот так:

```
var 
 f1,f2:TextFile;
 i,n,colonIndex:integer;
 s,k:string;
 c: char;
begin
  while not Eof(f1) do 
  begin
   Readln(f1,s);
   k:='';
   colonIndex := Pos(':', s) - 1;
   if colonIndex > 0 then
   begin
    for i:=colonIndex downto 1 do
    begin
      k:=k+s[i];
    end;
    k:=k+copy(s, colonIndex + 1, Length(s) - colonIndex);
   end;
  writeln(f2, k);
 end;
end.
```

Comment: Помогите переделать под мой код ?

Comment: Вставляете вместо вашего кода, оставляя readln и writeln для чтения/записи файла.

Comment: Так, у меня идет открытие и запись в файл. Не могу понять что место s:='13.06.2018:Документ№1'; прописать ? Заранее благодарна за помощь.

Comment: Изменил код, но из-за того, что вы обрезали часть, не уверен, что все удачно впишется, непонятны начала/концы циклов.

Answer (score 1):

Есть функция System.StrUtils ReverseString, измененный кусочек:

```
colonIndex := Pos(':', s);
if colonIndex > 0
then k := ReverseString(Copy(s, 1, colonIndex - 1)) + Copy(s, colonIndex, Length(s));
```